# Is there a perfect time at which to attempt to put google ads on your site

Tags: google-adsense

I have been waiting for my new online shop to reach above 150 unique visitors per day before I try to apply for the google ads campaign. I have tried once on another site that had about 40-50 views per day and it got refused.

So what would be a good indication that you can apply for the google ads program and have high hopes that you will be accepted?

Comment: Are you talking about Google AdSense? Do you want to promote your site, or do you want to earn money from ads? Sorry I did not get your question.

Comment: I want to display Google Ads on my site and earn money from that

Comment: I have changed the tag of your question, and stephen answer is perfectly right.

Answer (score 2):

Google AdSense doesn't have minimum traffic requirements to apply.  They do however have minimum content requirements.   You shouldn't apply until your site has at least 50 pages of content.  Your site also needs to meet all their other policies and requirements including:

- No prohibited content such as adult, alcohol, or drugs.
- No pirated copyrighted material
- No counterfeit goods
- No traffic from pay to click sources
- Content in supported languages
- A nice looking site with clear content and navigation areas

A certain amount of traffic is required to actually get paid.   Google doesn't issue checks until your account has accrued $100 (USD).   A typical site needs about 50,000 visitors to make $100.   To make $100 every month you need about 1500 daily visitors.

Those numbers are based on a $2 "page RPM" (revenue per thousand page views).  RPM of between $1 and $5 are typical.   The actual amount depends on many factors including:

- Ad placement on your site (Prominence, colors, and number of ads)
- Your sector and niche (Advertisers pay more in some categories than others)
- The country and language of your traffic  (Advertisers pay more for visitors from richer countries)
- The devices your users typically use (mobile traffic is worth far less than desktop traffic)

I personally wouldn't try to put ads on a site until it is at the point where the revenue stream would be meaningful to me.     I have several smaller on which I don't use ads.   I'd rather have the better user experience of no ads and let the sites grow faster because of it.

You will also have an issue applying with the new site because you applied with an old site.   You can only have one application from a Google account.   Your first option is to work with the old site and get the application approved for it.   At that point you can use AdSense on all your sites.   Otherwise you will have to apply from a different Google acount.

Comment: Well, I've got 116 + pages so that's not a problem, it's a well-designed site that took me months to create and has everything that the minimum requirements are. Though the 1500 visitors daily just slew the dragon for me. This is a site that's focused on a small European country. If I'm getting 1500 views per day I might as well not go for ads for measly $100 since it is an online shop and it will generate a lot more earnings from customers alone. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: Ads are great for informational sites that gets lots of visitors, but don't sell anything directly.   On an eCommerce site I think they get in the way and reduce sales without providing much additional revenue.

Comment: I would agree - don't put ads on a site that is selling a product because the adverts are only competing with your products, and I'm sure your products are much more lucrative for you! I only use them on information 'enthusiast' type sites where they don't intrude on the user experience too much; and keep them away from my commercial sites.

Answer (score 0):

From what I heard from some of my friends that it is kinda hard to get approved by Adsense these days. I think you should concentrate on your content for now and apply when you have as Stephen mentioned 50 pages. I think you should also wait until you get some decent number of visitors. The type of content also plays a big part on getting approved by Adsense. And even after that you dont get approved by Adsense then there are other ways to monetize like Affiliates and paid promotions.

I got my adsense approved with one page with nothing but a search box on it and with zero content, btw that was 10-12 years ago cant exactly remember.